# some questions about the typeof operator of IE9

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have been learning the Definitive Guide of JavaScript.i got a question about the typeof  opertor. I run the script "alert(typeof window.alert)" in IE9 it proved to be return "function". but  if i remove the "DOCTYPE" definition at the top of the html,the result turn to be "object".

I want to know why "DOCTYPE" definition exists or not make  a  different result.
can anyone help me ? 3Q!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE<=8 used to have peculiar object bindings, and the `typeof` operator returned `object` where it should have returned `function`.

Removing the doctype puts IE into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). This makes sure that older websites can be viewed and older scripts don't throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a good explanation:

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype